# allow-navigation isn't taking precedence over allow-intent on iOS

Tags: ios, cordova, cordova-plugins, pwabuilder

I generated an iOS and Android Pollyfill for my PWA app with [PWAbuilder](https://www.pwabuilder.com/). It is working great on Android, but I'm running into an issue on the iOS one.

I want external links to open in the external browser, so I added this `allow-intent`:

```
<allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
```

This worked fine, if I click on any external link (**not-under-my-domain.com**), it opens in the external browser.

For opening **my-domain.com** within the app, I added

```
<allow-navigation hap-rule="yes" href="*://my-domain.com/*" />
```

According to the docs, `allow-navigation` should take precedence over `allow-intent`, but it does not seem to be working.

Then if I click on any link within my domain, such as **/other-page**, it opens in the external browser - which isn't expected, it should open within the app.

I would like to have any link not defined in `allow-navigation` to open in the external browser, and all others (under **my-domain.com**) within the app.

Any ideas?

Comment: what's your cordova-ios version? I've been trying with 4.5.4 and seems to work fine. I've created an app that loads google and allows google navigation and it does the search, but the results are open in safari. Also tried loading different `www.example.com` urls after allowing `<allow-navigation hap-rule="yes" href="*://www.example.com/*" />` and all of them open inside the app.

Comment: It's possible that you need to add: 
<allow-navigation href="*" />
<allow-intent href="*" />
Don't allow insert asterisk, you need to add inside the asterisk -> *
and 
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <!--Not a recommended way, there are better solutions available-->
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>

Comment: @jcesarmobile I generated the iOS version using https://www.pwabuilder.com and I'm having a hard time to find the version. How can I tell it based on the Xcode project?

Comment: @Lito I tried to leave it with "", but it didn't do the trick.

Comment: @PabloCantero `I said you need to add inside the asterisk -> *`, but web don't allow set asterisk `<allow-navigation href="*" /> <allow-intent href="*" />`

Comment: The Cordova.js fiel should contain the Cordova version

Comment: @jcesarmobile I found this `PLATFORM_VERSION_BUILD_LABEL = '4.1.1'` on ios/www/cordova.js, is that the version?

Comment: @Lito understood, thanks! Changing to `<allow-navigation href="*" /> <allow-intent href="*" />` is causing all links to open in the external browser.

Comment: @jcesarmobile upgrading cordova did the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after all it seems the problem was with my outdated version of cordova. I upgraded the cordova version following @jcesarmobile's suggestion on the comments and it is working now.

```
npm install cordova -g
cordova plugin save
cordova platform rm ios
cordova platform add ios
```